# configuración datatables.net en JavaScript, ASP.NET CORE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-core

estoy con otro inconveniente con datatables en JavaScript.

el datatables me crea la siguiente tabla, pero a la hora de imprimir en excel o con la funcion 'print' no me muestra agrupados.

- Necesito poder imprimir agrupado.
- En messageTop poner el nombre del usuario que corresponda como encabezado.
- En messageBottom el nombre del usuario como pie de firma y el valor total.

Cómo podría hacer? re-busqué en la librería datatables.net y en internet pero no encuentro cómo hacer este dato.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
Fecha User  Valor
04/27 Admin 5.28
04/25 Admin 0.63
04/27 Admin 0.00
**name:Admin  5.91**

04/21 Admi2 4.00
04/20 Admi2 1.50
**name:Admi2  5.50**
```

```
    <script>
        var tabla;       
            tabla = $("#tbdata").DataTable({
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Excel',
                        titleAttr: 'Excel',
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        messageTop: 'For de period of ',
                        messageBottom: 'Total ',
                    },
                    'pageLength'
                ],
                responsive: true,

                "ajax": {
                    "url": '@Url.Action("Rep", "Adm")?fInicio=' + $("#txtfInicio").val() + "&fFin=" + $("#txtfFin").val(),
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "fecha" },                   
                    { "data": "usuario" },
                    { "data": "valor"}
                ],
                order: [[1, 'asc']],
                rowGroup: {
                    startRender: function (rows, group) {
                        var grupo = group.split(",")
                        return $('<tr class="bg-light">').append(    
                        )
                    },
                    endRender: function (rows, group) {
                        var grupo = group.split(",")
                        var total = rows.data().pluck("valor").reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
                        return $('<tr class="bg-light">').append(
                            $('<td colspan="2">').text('Name: ' + grupo[0]),
                            $('<td>').text('Total'),
                            $('<td>').text(total.toFixed(2))
                        )
                    },
                    dataSrc: 'usuario',
                    dataSrc: function (row) {
                        return row.usuario;
                    }
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "visible": true, "targets": 0 },// esconde la columna que se requiera
                    { "visible": true, "targets": 1 },
                    { "visible": false, "targets": 2 },
                ],
                language: {
                    url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/i18n/es-ES.json"
                }
            })
        })
        $("#btnbuscar").on("click", function () {
            var nueva_url = '@Url.Action("Rep", "Adm")?fInicio=' + $("#txtfInicio").val() + "&fFin=" + $("#txtfFin").val()
            tabla.ajax.url(nueva_url).load();
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Que es eso de "Agrupado?

Comment: La API de datatable.net me permite crear subtotales tipo en excel, en el ejemplo por usuario (**name:Admin  5.91**)